# Many-one reduction of $K^c$ to $A$

Tags: logic, computability, turing-machines

I saw some examples of reduction one of them is this:

We say set $B$ is many-one reducible to $A$ if there exists a total cumputable fucntion $f$ that:$$x\in B \iff f(x) \in A$$
and we write $B\leq_m A$.

Prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$K^c \le_m \{y: w_x = w_y\} $$
Where $K=\{e\in \mathbb{N}|e\in W_e\}$ and $w_e = Dom(\phi_e(x))$ is the set of all numbers that on which the e-th Turing machine halt

---

**Update**

I removed unnecessary sentences(Rice's theorem, etc.). I realize if we prove that any $\sum^0_{n}$ set is many-one reducible to an arbitrary set $P\in\sum^0_{n+1}$, we can get the result. see for more [Arithmetic hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy)

We know $\phi\,_{e,t}(x)\!\downarrow$ is computable relation so we get these results that come below:

- $A\leq_m B \iff A\,^c\leq_m B\,^c$ so needs to prove $K \le_m \{y: w_x \ne w_y\} $. Also know that the set if $Y=\{y: w_x \ne w_y\}$ than $Y \in \sum^0_2$.
  $$y\in Y \iff \exists <s,p>[\:\forall s\:[\:\phi_{y,t}(p)\!\downarrow \wedge\ \phi_{x,t}(p)\!\uparrow\:]\:]$$
  where $\phi_{x,t}(p)\downarrow$ means $x$-th Turring machien halt on $p$ after atmost $t$ step other wise we write $\phi_{x,t}(p)\uparrow$ and $<.,.>$ is a one-one function maps $\mathbb{N}^2$ onto $\mathbb{N}$
- $K\in\sum^0_1$:
  $$x \in K \iff \exists \:s \:\phi\,_{x,s}(x)\!\downarrow$$

Comment: can you please add some clarification to your notation, for example what is $w_x,w_y$.

Comment: Also I do not understand your comment about Rice's Theorem needing the index set not to contain any index of the empty set?

Comment: Sorry for that I edited it. @ConnorLockhart

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying edits, I will answer your question when I get home and have access to a computer but for now a comment on Rice's theorem. There is no problem with an index set containing an index of the empty set, there are many natural index sets which do contain such indices. 
(consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set_(computability) ) 

The restriction that the index set itself cannot be the empty set is required because this set is computable, take a turing machine which never halts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.
About conting that indices Copper asume that A dose not contain any of them to prove first one(K reducible to A). I edited text and add the proof.

Comment: Why has my question been closed?

Comment: I do not know, I was going to answer it but got a little busy so i got delayed. Can the question be unclosed?

Comment: I don't know, I edited the post and make it clear with more result.